# How can i read lines in a textfile with RUBY

Tags: ruby

I am new in ruby programming. I am trying to read a textfile line by line.

Here is my sample textfile:

```
john
doe
john_d
somepassword
```

Here is my code:

```
f = File.open('input.txt', 'r')
a = f.readlines
n = a[0]
s = a[1]
u = a[2]
p = a[3]
str = "<user><name=\"#{n}\" surname=\"#{s}\" username=\"#{u}\" password=\"#{p}\"/></user>"
File.open('result.txt', 'w') { |file| file.print(str) }
```

The output should look like this:

```
<user><name="john" surname="doe" username="john_d" password="somepassword"/></user>
```

But the result.txt looks like this. It includes newline character for every line:

```
<user><name="john
" surname="doe
" username="john_d
" password="somepassword"/></user>
```

How can i correct this?

Comment: Is your problem reading a file line-by-line, or is it the printing of a string whose content is determined in part by the contents of a file? One way of doing the latter, for example, is to "gulp" the entire contents of the file as a single string (rather than reading it line-by-line)  and then extract from that string the substrings of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It includes newline character for every line, because there is a newline character at the end of every line.

Just removed it when you don't need it:

```
n = a[0].gsub("\n", '')
s = a[1].gsub("\n", '')
# ...
```

Comment: turns out, this solution is the right answer. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by spickermann, also just change line two into:

```
a = f.readlines.map! { |line| line.chomp }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @iGian already mentioned, `chomp` is a good option to clean up your text. I am not sure which version of Ruby you are using, but here is the link to the official Ruby version 2.5 documentation on `chomp` just so you see how it is going to help you: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-chomp

See the content of variable `a` after using `chomp`:

```
2.4.1 :001 > f = File.open('input.txt', 'r')
=> #<File:input.txt> 
2.4.1 :002 > a = f.readlines.map! {|line| line.chomp}
=> ["john", "doe", "john_d", "somepassword"]
```

Depending on how many other corner cases you expect to see from your input string, here is also another suggestion that can help you to clean up your strings: `strip` with link to its official documentation with examples: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-strip

See the content of variable `a` after using `strip`:

```
2.4.1 :001 > f = File.open('input.txt', 'r')
=> #<File:input.txt> 
2.4.1 :002 > a = f.readlines.map! {|line| line.strip}
=> ["john", "doe", "john_d", "somepassword"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FName = 'temp'

File.write FName, "john
doe
john_d
somepassword"
  #=> 28
```

Here are two ways.

```
s = "<user><name=\"%s\" surname=\"%s\" username=\"%s\" password=\"%s\"/></user>"

puts s % File.readlines(FName).map(&:chomp)
  # <user><name="john" surname="doe" username="john_d" password="somepassword"/></user>
puts s % File.read(FName).split("\n")
  # <user><name="john" surname="doe" username="john_d" password="somepassword"/></user>
```

See [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-25) and, as mentioned in that doc, [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Comment: I have solved the problem with the answer above, using gsub. Thanks for your help. This is also helpful for feature reference.

Comment: Considering that each line contains a single newline character (`"\n"`), and that character appears at the end of the string, there are many `String` methods that could be used to remove them. Two that do not take an argument are `chomp` and `chop`. Two that takes a single argument are `delete` and `slice` (aka `[]=`, as in `"abc\n"[0..-2] #=> "abc"`) .Three that, like `gsub`, take two arguments, are `sub`, `tr` and `tr_s`. `chomp`, being purpose-built for the task, is normally the method of choice for removing a trailing newline.